# How long does store bought ranch dressing last once opened and does it need to be refrigerated?

Tags: salad

once we open the bottle and reseal with our own bottle would it need to be refrigerated? we are looking to buy in bulk and rebottle the dressing.
Thank you

Comment: In my experience, most Ranch dressing labels say "Refrigerate after opening" ... But I'm far from a ranch dressing expert

Comment: You have to assume that you have to keep refrigeratred, unless the bottle tells you otherwise. For shelf life in the fridge, see the "Shelf-stable until opened" section in the answer to the linked question. If you don't know if the dressing is high- or low-acid, assume it's low acid (the shorter shelf life) or test it with a pH strip.